# What determines WvW river drake disposition?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In the borderlands of WvW, there are some [river drakes](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/River_Drake) in and to the west of [Battle's Hollow](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Battle%27s_Hollow). Sometimes when I encounter these drakes, their names are shown in yellow to indicate that they are neutral, while other times their names are shown in red to indicate that they are hostile.

What determines the [disposition](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Non-player_character#Disposition) of these river drakes?

Comment: Do you remember if it was your home borderlands when they were neutral? That's the only thing I can think of, I don't recall any events pertaining to them.

Comment: @mmatthews I was in my home borderlands last night and they were hostile. I've considered that, who owns the bay keep, and who controls bloodlust in that map, but none of those seem to be the answer.

Comment: Update on things that DON'T affect them, as I may have previously thought: the nearby "middle lake" sentry, and nearby southern tower.

Comment: I've never seen these drakes hostile unless I hit them first.